# Area of largest inscribed rectangle in an ellipse. Can I square the area before taking the derivative?

Tags: calculus

So say I have an ellipse defined like this:

$$\frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}{4} = 1$$

I have to find the largest possible area of an inscribed rectangle.

So the area ($A$) of a rectangle is $2x2y=4xy$. Also we can redefine $y$ in terms of $x$:

$$\frac{y^2}{4} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{9}$$
$$y^2 = 4 - \frac{4x^2}{9}$$
$$y = \sqrt{4 - \frac{4x^2}{9}}$$

So the area function is now:

$$A=4x \cdot \sqrt{4 - \frac{4x^2}{9}}$$
$$A' = \frac{4x}{2 \cdot \frac{-8x}{9}} + \sqrt{4 - \frac{4x^2}{9}} \cdot 4$$

Is this the right track? Was there something simpler I could have done? this looks gnarly? Can someone help me finish this up?

So this track seems to difficult, another approach. Can I square the area first, find the derivative of that to solve for x?

So the Area = $4x \cdot \sqrt{4 - \frac{4x^2}{9}}$

Is this valid?

$$Area^2 = 16x^2 \cdot (4 - \frac{4x^2}{9}$$

$$= 64x^2 - \frac{64x^4}{9}$$

Derivative:

$$ \frac{d}{dx} Area^2 = 128x - \frac{256x^3}{9}$$
$$128x(1-\frac{2x^2}{9}$$

So critical values: $x = 0, \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$

because the derivative equals 0 when:

$$2x^2 = 9$$
$$x = \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Plugging this value of x into y we get that $y = \sqrt{2}$ so the Area is 3.

Is this valid? If so why? Does squaring not cause any problems?

Comment: Your first term in $A'$ is incorrect

Comment: @rbird I don't see why....

Comment: If $y$ is a function of $x$, derivative of $y^2= 2 y y'^{'} $.  Derivatives of $y,y^2$ vanish together. Avoid cumbersome calculation by squaring. Also applying Chain Rule to the squared quantity, it goes much faster $ \dfrac{x^2}{1-x^2/9}=\dfrac{-2x}{-2x/9}=9 \implies x=\pm \dfrac{3}{\sqrt2}$

Answer (score 3):

You are over-complicating it. Affine maps preserve the ratios of areas and, in a circle, the inscribed squares are pretty obviously the largest inscribed quadrilaterals. Their area is $\frac{2}{\pi}$ times the area of the circle. By applying $\varphi:(x,y)\mapsto(ax,by)$ the ellipse with equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ is mapped into a circle. By applying $\varphi^{-1}$ we get that

> **A**. In the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, the largest inscribed rectangle (which is also one of the largest inscribed quadrilaterals) is symmetric with respect to the axis of the ellipse and its area equals $2ab$.

By the very same principle,

> **B**. In the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, the area of the largest inscribed triangle equals $\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}ab$.
>
> **C**. In a triangle $ABC$ the largest inscribed ellipse is tangent to the sides at their midpoints and the center of such ellipse lies at the centroid of $ABC$. This is the [Steiner inellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_inellipse) of $ABC$.

Comment: I don't know these principles yet and I have to brute force it.

Comment: @Jwan622: I believe that *affine maps preserve the ratios of areas* is a much more elementary concept than $\frac{d}{dx}$. Now that you are aware of it, why not to use it?

Comment: How can we convince ourselves that the largest rectangle has sides parallel to the main ellipse axis ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: by applying $\varphi^{-1}$ to all the inscribed squares in the circle.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: if the rectangle and the ellipse are not aligned, no affine map can lead to a square inscribed in a circle. But such a configuration cannot be rejected a priori.

Comment: Maybe I did not explain me clearly. We know all the quadrilaterals with maximal area inscribed in a circle. By pulling them back, we get all the quadrilaterals with maximal area inscribed in a ellipse. One of them is a rectangle. In particular it is the largest inscribed rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Hint...it would be a lot easier if you wrote $$(x,y)=(3\cos\theta,2\sin\theta)$$ then obtain an expression for the area of the rectangle in terms of $\theta$ and differentiate...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in right track but your expression for the first derivative of $A$ need a little touch. I put it in more clear way:

$$A=4x \cdot \sqrt{4 - \frac{4x^2}{9}}=4x \left(4-\frac{4x^2}{9}\right)^{1/2}$$ Thus,
$$A' = 4 \left(4-\frac{4x^2}{9}\right)^{1/2} + 4x \left(4-\frac{4x^2}{9}\right)^{-1/2}\left(\frac{-8x}{9} \right)=4 \left(4-\frac{4x^2}{9}\right)^{1/2} - \frac{32x^2}{9} \left(4-\frac{4x^2}{9}\right)^{-1/2}=\frac{36 \left(4-\frac{4x^2}{9}\right) - 32x^2} {9\left(4-\frac{4x^2}{9}\right)^{1/2}}=\frac{4 \left(36-4x^2\right) - 288x^2} {81\left(4-\frac{4x^2}{9}\right)^{1/2}}=\frac{144 - 304x^2} {81\left(4-\frac{4x^2}{9}\right)^{1/2}}$$
To find the maximum for $A$, set $A'=0$ since $-3\le x\le +3$, and hence $\left(4-\frac{4x^2}{9}\right)^{1/2}\ne0$. Therefore, $144 - 304x^2=0$ when $A'-0$ and $x=\pm\sqrt\frac{19}{9}$.
$$A_{max}=4\left(\sqrt\frac{19}{9}\right) \left( \sqrt{4 - \frac{4\left(\sqrt\frac{19}{9}\right)^2}{9}}\right)=8\left(\sqrt\frac{19}{9}\right) \left( \frac{\sqrt{62}}{9}\right)=\frac{8\sqrt{1178}}{27}$$

**Note:** The $\pm x$ values for rectangle are symmetrical points on major axis of ellipse where vertical legs of rectangle meet.